# A claim regarding Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-series

Claim : "A periodic function 
$f(u)$
 satisfying $$\int_{0}^{1}f(u)du=0$$
 can generally expanded into a Fourier Series: 
$$f(u)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}[a_m\sin{(2 \pi m u)}+b_m\cos{(2 \pi m u)}]$$ "

This is written on Greiner's Classical Mechanics when solving a Tautochrone problem.
Firstly,I don’t understand why we didn’t use the term $m=0$
 and Sencondly, how the integrand helps us to fulfill the Dirichlet conditions. That means,how do we know that the period is 1?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read Greiner closely, $f(x)$ has period $1$  because that's how it is constructed. 
$a_0=0$ because $a_0=\int_{0}^{1}f(u)du=0$